# NDIS proto sample and ethernet bridge

Tags: c++, windows-7-x64, ndis

I was trying to write a test bridge between two ethernet adapters using the NDIS proto example given in the WDK for Win 7. So far just got the driver and prototest built. 
Now I was wondering how to proceeed?
Is there any way to bind to only a couple of adapters at one time?

Comment: @Jeffrey-Tippet Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An NDIS protocol automatically binds to *all* supported adapters.  So you don't need to do extra work to get NDISPROT to bind over two Ethernet NICs.

Once you've built the driver, all you need to do is:

1. Install the driver (use `INetCfgClassSetup::Install` as illustrated in the bindview sample; or for casual experimentation, the NIC properties GUI has an **Add...** button that lets you install protocols with a GUI).
2. Start the driver service (use `StartService` API; or for casual experimentation, `net start ndisprot` will do).

That's it.  NDIS will call your protocol's ProtocolBindAdpaterEx handler for each Ethernet NIC on the system.  This callback is named `NdisprotBindAdapter` in the sample.

Use `!ndiskd.protocol` to verify that your protocol is now bound to multiple miniports.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, can I bind to only selected adapters?

Comment: also, is it the right way to make ethernet bridge or should I use miniport or filter driver? Do you know of any example ethernet bridge driver in NDIS6.x?

Comment: To bind to selected adapters: in usermode, use INetCfgBindingPath::Enable(FALSE) to disable bindings to certain adapters.  In kernelmode: in your ProtocolBindAdapterEx handler, just choose to not call NdisOpenAdapterEx if you don't want to bind.

Comment: Windows comes with an Ethernet bridge, so that's the best example to compare with.  It is implemented as a MUX-IM driver, which is fairly complicated to get right.  The advantage to a MUX-IM versus a regular protocol is the bridged adapters appear as 1 unified network interface to the OS.  If it's ok that the bridged adapters each appear independently to the OS, then you don't need a MUX-IM, and a protocol is sufficient.

Comment: no problem in appearing the bridged adapters appearing independently to OS, But what I'm now confused at is, after reading this link http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.development.device.drivers/2004-04/1377.html Is it possible to achieve the same by modifying passthru? If yes, wondering how?

Comment: Don't use passthru for this.  Since this answer requires more space, I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792238/ndis-6-x-ethernet-bridge-driver